# How to get 7 bytes length only DES key

Tags: java

```
{
 KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
 SecretKey myKey = keyGen.generateKey();
 byte[] data = myKey.getEncoded();
 String encodedKey;
 encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
 System.out.println("My key1 :" +myKey);
 System.out.println("My key2 :" +encodedKey);
 System.out.println("My key3 :" +data);
}
```

it returns

```
My key1 :com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@fffe79f6  
My key2 :dg61j8hRCNY=   
My key3 :[B@2ac1fdc4
```

Could u guys tell me how do i get 7 bytes KEY , no more KEY PREFIX `com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey`

Because i want to save my 7 chars ASCII into a file to HIDE it somewhere in the planet.

Comment: The problem is that you're just calling `toString()` on `SecretKey`. What 7 bytes are you expecting? What's wrong with just using `data`?

Comment: My key1 :com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@fffe79f6   that's why . i just need only 7 bytes KEY not com.sun.......
Because DES only need 7 bytes for a KEY.

Comment: You're currently just printing out the result of calling `toString`. That's not what you want. I *strongly* suspect that you just want to use `data`... it's not clear why you're printing out `myKey` at all, nor what you expected it to print.

Comment: oh let me Edit my question. Anyway Thanks . Anyway i just want a KEY ( 7 bytes or 7 Chars )

Comment: Now you're calling `toString` on a byte array, which still isn't going to do you much good. Have you looked at how long `data` is (not as a string, just on its own)? By the looks of it, it's 8 bytes rather than 7, which seems reasonable... why would you expect it to be 7 bytes anyway?

Comment: DES key has 56 bits means 7 bytes ( 7 * 8 = 56 ) so i need only KEY to show and read it...

Comment: It looks like you've got 8 bytes which is 56 bits + 8 parity bits. So if you only need 7 bytes, ditch the parity part - I suspect that's the last byte of `data`. Not sure what you mean by "show and read it" (nor why you insist on putting key in capitals every time...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet : sr for my bad english . first this is my homework explain DES key . So i need to have KEY in ASCII. but the result gave me 12 Chars (12 * 7 = 84 bits ) ,but DES key only have 7 Bytes ( with 1 byte parity is 8 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different issues here.

1. The key returned by DES has eight bytes because it has one parity bit per byte
2. The conversion to ASCII using Base64 needs more characters than source bytes as it only uses five bits per character
3. ASCII itself uses only seven bits per character so even if you convert directly to ASCII using all possible characters instead of only 64, you will need eight bytes

If you don’t want to store the parity bit, you can drop it as follows:

```
static byte[] dropParity(byte[] desKey) {
    if(desKey.length!=8) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    BitSet in=BitSet.valueOf(desKey);
    BitSet out=new BitSet(56);
    for(int byteIndex=0, inIndex=0, outIndex=0; byteIndex<8; byteIndex++, inIndex++)
      for(int bitIndex=0; bitIndex<7; bitIndex++) out.set(outIndex++, in.get(inIndex++));
    byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
    if(byteArray.length<7) // last byte(s) are zero
      byteArray=Arrays.copyOf(byteArray, 7);
    return byteArray;
}
static byte[] regenerateParity(byte[] desKey) {
    if(desKey.length!=7) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    BitSet in=BitSet.valueOf(desKey);
    BitSet out=new BitSet(64);
    for(int byteIndex=0, inIndex=0, outIndex=0; byteIndex<8; byteIndex++)
    {
      boolean even=true;
      for(int bitIndex=0; bitIndex<7; bitIndex++) {
        final boolean bit = in.get(inIndex++);
        out.set(outIndex++, bit);
        even ^= bit;
      }
      out.set(outIndex++, even);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

These two methods allow to convert the eight byte array to a seven byte array and back by dropping and regenerating the parity bit. Keep in mind that these bytes are not ASCII characters.

---

If you want to transfer a key through a channel which only accepts ASCII characters, you may use a direct encoding which uses seven bits per character. As said, that will still occupy eight bytes per key.

```
static String dropParityAndConvertToASCII(byte[] desKey) {
    if(desKey.length!=8) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    char[] ch=new char[8];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) ch[i]=(char)((desKey[i]>>1)&0x7F);
    return new String(ch);
}
static byte[] convertFromASCIIAndAddParityBit(String desKey) {
    if(desKey.length()!=8) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    byte[] ba=new byte[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int b = desKey.charAt(i)<<1;
        ba[i] = (byte)(b | Integer.bitCount(b)&1^1);
    }
    return ba;
}
```

The obstacle here is that the parity bit is the lowest bit while the unused bit of the ASCII encoding is the highest. So the key bytes are shifted by one bit and the highest bit set to zero to create ASCII bytes. When converting back, the value are shifted back and the parity bit is recalculated.

But note that not all ASCII characters are printable characters. If you want an encoding that is displayable, you have to resort to an encoding like Base64 and live with the fact that it produces more characters than key bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The byte array `data` is the key you are asking for.

However, it is NOT in ASCII.

If you want to save it as text (ASCII), that's why you have to use an encoded format, e.g. using base64, like your `encodedKey`.

You can read it back later, and base64 decode it and get back the 7 byte key `data`.

Comment: hmmm ASCII need 8 bits ( 1 byte ) per Character.
but my encodekey returns "dg61j8hRCNY=" 12 bytes length. 
My question is how to get only 7 bytes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
_"ASCII encodes 128 specified characters into seven-bit binary integers as shown by the ASCII chart on the right."_

ASCII is 7bit only, as you also know 1 byte = 8bit. you cannot represent a 7 bytes of data in a 7 character ASCII

Comment: So the result is 12 chars ( 12 * 7 = 84 bits) ... so hard for me to explain my homework to teacher

Comment: Base64 converts every 3 bytes of data into 4 chars, so you have 7 bytes of data 7-9 bytes of data would convert to 12 chars

Comment: Actually if you want to prove that the key is 7 bytes, simply print out `data.length`

Comment: WOOW This is the answer i'm looking for. Thanks